# MT2002 Missing reference in Xamarin Forms IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When I am trying to deploy the application to device I am getting this strange error. Any idea how to fix it?

```
/***/MTOUCH: Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Log::Warning(System.String,System.String)" reference from "Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" (MT2002) (Project.iOS)
```

Its working fine in iOS simulator and on Android Device

Answer (score 0):

Try to erase the bin/obj folders from your project and do a clean and rebuild.

Do you have the latest Xamarin.Forms packages updates?

It looks like a reference is missing so it may be a few things like the build configuration of your project or the NuGet packages itself I hope this helps.